# Why does Nick Fury say that Loki's staff is powered by the Tesseract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, infinity-stones

In *[The Avengers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/quotes)*, when the whole team is discussing Loki on the helicarrier, this quote comes up:

> Steve Rogers: Let's start with that stick of his. It may be magical, but it works an awful lot like a Hydra weapon.
>
> Nick Fury: I don't know about that, **but it is powered by the cube**. And I'd like to know how Loki used it to turn two of the sharpest men I know into his personal flying monkeys.

Given that the "stick" has been revealed to hold the Mind Stone and the Tesseract actually contains the Space Stone, is this simply incorrect and Fury was mistaken at the time? Or are the Infinity Stones actually linked to each other in some esoteric way?

Comment: The out-of-universe answer is that it the scepter being an infinity stone was a retcon.

Comment: @ibid That'd be a perfect answer if you have a source for it

Comment: @Dubukay - No source, that's just what I assumed to be obvious when I saw it.

Answer (score 14):

Out-of-universe, I suspect they hadn't decided yet that the Tesseract *or* Loki's staff held an Infinity Stone. That fact raises a number of questions, not the least of which is "Why was Thanos willing to give away one of the Infinity Stones he's so desperate to get?". So at the time the dialogue was written, it's most likely that the idea *was* that Loki's staff was powered by the cube in some sense. We don't even hear the word "Infinity Stone" used on-screen until the end of *Thor 2* a year later, and even then it's basically just an Easter Egg.

In-universe, Fury was just wrong. His conclusion makes sense based on just what we see in *Avengers*, so it's not surprising he made the mistake. The connection between the two objects remains all the way through to the end, where we see that the scepter has the power to close the cube's portals.

Whether or not there is any kind of link between the Stones, we don't know. Since the end of *Avengers* I don't believe we've seen two of the Stones in the same place at the same time; the closest we've come is that *we* know The Collector had two of them (the Reality and Power Stones) in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, but the Aether was never shown or mentioned on screen.

It's possible that in *Infinity War* we do find out the Stones can interact with each other, but until then, all we know is that Fury was mistaken.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR: Nick Fury was stating what he believed to be the truth. But yes, he was mistaken.**

---

When we first see the Tesseract in the film, it is being held in a secret S.H.I.E.L.D. facility where Dr. Erik Selvig is experimenting on it. As Fury enters the room, Selvig explains that the artifact - which they know very little about - is behaving erratically:

> **SELVIG:** The Tesseract is not only active, it's... misbehaving.
>
> **FURY:** How soon can we pull the plug?
>
> **SELVIG:** It's an energy source. Each time we turn off the power, it turns it back on.

Immediately after that conversation, the Tesseract seemingly opens a portal all by itself and Loki comes through holding the staff. The stone in the staff's head is visibly glowing the same color as the Tesseract.

[image]

Neither Fury nor anyone else present knows about the Infinity Stones yet, so from his perspective there is every reason to believe that the staff and the Tesseract are linked.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you forgetting that the Tesseract opened a portal that send the Red Skull to outer space? Space stone quality. And Loki's scepter could control minds. Mind stone quality. Everthing adds up. Only S.H.I.E.L.D didn't know it yet. And after Infinity War it seems quite clear thet the Infinity Stones   are connected from the beginning of the universe. And every Infinity Stone has some kind of energy to it that probably can be harnessed. So if other Stones made it to earth they would have been used by humans to make weapons out of it. Like with the Tesseract.

Comment: Although this is *technically* and answer, this reads more like a comment. Could you elaborate?